# Teamcity continuous delivery

Tags: javascript, git, teamcity

I have actually an angular2 application which I want to build and deploy through teamcity.

Actually, I can build the app (with some build steps, like converting .ts or .es6 files to .js files, npm install some modules etc...)

Now, I need that when these commands are okay (I mean, no bug) everything built is delivery .

Moreover, I need it only from git, not from a local repository.

**Explanations**

Actually, I want to :

- git add / commit / push
- run my build (from the git repository so)
- deploy everything generated to the corresponding ftp host

**What I have tried**

[This plugin](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/Deployer+plugin) works great for deploying repositories from *my local machine*.

In fact, if I dont git add / commit / push, and instead I run directly the build with this plugin, I have some difference between my remote and my local repositories, because it seems that the plugin is based on the local repository.

I want to deploy only with the remote git files (implying that my .ts and .es6 are not converted before the build)

Do you know what I mean ?

Thanks for advance

EDIT :

So in this case I have to build with :

- npm install tsc (remote git)
- launch command line "tsc" (remote git)
- git clone / pull data (remote to local git)
- npm install tsc (local git)
- launch command line "tsc" (local git)
- deploy file generated (local git)

???

Comment: It makes sense to me that a tool like TeamCity will need the files locally, so it would need a local copy of the repository. That doesn't have to be *your* local repository. You can make TeamCity pull changes from another repository before making a build. So you add/commit/push (to GitHub?), TeamCity pulls your changes, makes a build, and deploys it. And yes, that means that the repository will have two checkouts on your local machine, if TeamCity runs on that same machine. Or you must make TeamCity forget about Git altogether and let it work from your copy.

Comment: I've editted my post